# Does hawt.io still work with camel-http?

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

We are running standalone java application using apache camel.  We've embedded haw.io in the application and everything seems to be working.

When we add a dependency on camel-http, hawtio will no longer start.  Are these not compatible?

This is the exception we are getting:

---

```
2013-07-01 13:55:10,002 WARN  [Thread-5] - HawtioLoader.run (HawtioLoader.java:35) - hawt.io failed to run
java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.FilterRegistration"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:806) ~[?:1.6.0_51]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:487) ~[?:1.6.0_51]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:625) ~[?:1.6.0_51]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) ~[?:1.6.0_51]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) ~[?:1.6.0_51]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283) ~[?:1.6.0_51]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58) ~[?:1.6.0_51]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197) ~[?:1.6.0_51]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.6.0_51]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) ~[?:1.6.0_51]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) ~[?:1.6.0_51]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) ~[?:1.6.0_51]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) ~[?:1.6.0_51]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:129) ~[jetty-webapp-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.3.v20120416]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:109) ~[jetty-webapp-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.3.v20120416]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:97) ~[jetty-webapp-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.3.v20120416]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.java:171) ~[jetty-webapp-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.3.v20120416]
at io.hawt.embedded.Main.run(Main.java:56) ~[hawtio-embedded-1.1.jar:?]
at HawtioLoader.run(HawtioLoader.java:33) [classes/:?]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that both hawt.io and camel-http will include some javax-packages. From what I remember when I had this problem the solution was to look at the chained dependencies (in for example Eclipse) and find packages that are linked in from both. When you have found them (probably javax.servlet-something) exclude them from the camel-http dependency definition and your project will most likely work.

/S Laven

Comment: Yep.  This worked:



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>